# GameMaker Studio 2 - Multiple Events - Draw if mouse_enter event

Tags: events, draw, game-maker-studio-2

i'd like to draw something over my sprite when the mouse is on it.
Something like that (in the draw event of my object) :

```
if(ev_mouse_enter)draw_text(x,y,hp);
```

But it's not working (i know why).
I've been thinking about using some boolean to counter that.
Is it my only option ?

Comment: I'm certain that using a boolean to leave the draw_text() available is a solid option, you don't need to wonder about a different options if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're doing something like starcraft, they were billions, etc. you may want to have a 'selected' variable for the last unit / building / etc to keep that information up for them.

```
if (mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)) {
   if (place_meeting(mouse_x, mouse_y, oTarget)) {
      oGame.selectedUnit = other.id;
   }
}
```